# How to make hyperlink expand and flow to desired text simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am learning about web development. The code below works. I want to modify it such that, when the parent link on the left-hand-side with title "0.0 Forward" is clicked, 2 things happen simultaneously:

1-The list expands to show child nodes (this is working OK now).

2-The browser scrolls to show the text referenced on that hyperlink. The problem here is that the HREF value "ulExpCol"_10 refers to the ID within the navigation code, so that the expansion of the nodes can take place. Now since the HREF must point to an ID value, and since ID value has to be unique, I can't use the target id in the text body of value "item-0.0". If I do this, the expansion will not take pace.

So, it looks like I could either get the list to expand or the hyperlink to work but not both. Is this correct? Is there a work around this limitation (may be using js/jquery)?

Thanks.
Note: the body width is made small on purpose to demonstrate the question.

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/ekareem/3n7fd6xo/43/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <ul>
         <li>
            <a href="#ulExpCol_10" data-toggle="collapse" 
               onclick="$('#thisCollapsedChevron_10').toggleClass('fa-rotate-90')">
            <i id="thisCollapsedChevron_10"></i>
            0.0 Foreward
            </a>
            <!-- Children -->
            <ul id="ulExpCol_10" class="ml-3 list-unstyled collapse">
               <li>
                  <a href="#item-1.1" >
                  1.1 Introduction
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#item-1.2">
                  1.2 Cavalieri's Method of Indivisbles
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      ...
      <h2 id="item-0.0">
         Forewared
      </h2>
      ...
      <h3 id="item-1.1">
         1.1 Introduction
      </h3>
      ...
      <h3 id="item-1.2">
         1.2 Cavalieri's Method of Indivisbles
      </h3>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new data-attribute to the parent links ie: data-link="#item-0.0"

And then in document ready:

```
$("a[data-toggle]").each(function(){
    $(this).on('click', function(){
       var link = $('<a href="' + $(this).attr('data-link') + '">click</a>');
       link[0].click();
       link.remove();

    });
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/ag4rw69t/

Comment: This is a very good answer. If I place the navigation code in the left column in  a div say: <div class="col"><div id="leftNav">...</div>/</div>....How would I be able to restrict the toggle behavior to the navigation div only? Thanks much :)

Comment: You just  need to add some css - quick and dirty something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/53r9wcnj/

Comment: Thanks for the extra code. My point was how to make the links in the left column only behave in this specified way and not every other link in the page?. The CSS columns is not the issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that..just narrow the search to  $('#divleftcolumn').find("a[data-toggle]").each(function(){...